# Create a Boolean column by coercing factors to logical types in dataframe?

Tags: r

My dataframe looks like this:

```
  location       eco    

  Germany        eco    
  Netherlands    eco    
  USA            not-eco 
  Dubai          not-eco
```

I would like to create a new column in the dataframe and display TRUE if the location is "eco" and display FALSE if location is "not-eco". The result should look like this:

```
  location       eco        logical

  Germany        eco        TRUE
  Netherlands    eco        TRUE
  USA            not-eco    FALSE
  Dubai          not-eco    FALSE
```

How to do this with R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can compare the `"eco"` values in the column `eco` and create a logical column.

```
df$logical <- df$eco == "eco"
df

#     location     eco logical
#1     Germany     eco    TRUE
#2 Netherlands     eco    TRUE
#3         USA not-eco   FALSE
#4       Dubai not-eco   FALSE
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(location = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("Dubai",  
"Germany", "Netherlands", "USA"), class = "factor"), eco = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("eco", "not-eco"), class = "factor")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is absolutely correct!I made a mistake in the description of the problem and edited it.